# How to enable fast charging of Android phones on Linux?

Tags: linux, android, battery

My Dell XPS 15 has both Windows 10 and Gentoo Linux installed. On Windows, when I connect plug in my Android, I got a *charging fast* notification; on Linux, when I do the same, I got a *charging slowly* notification.

Same machine, same phone, same cable. I think something is missing/wrong with my Linux kernel/module. But I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: That feature may depend on proprietary software that was installed in Windows.